# Raspberry Pi component compatibility with other models

Tags: pi-2

For Christmas I want to buy a Raspberry Pi 2 and a Starter Learning kit with components. I have a budget of £50 for the Raspberry Pi itself, and a budget of £35 for the kit with components. I've found the two on eBay, and the Raspberry Pi comes with a case, a HDMI cable, an Ethernet Cable, a USB Wifi Nano, a Power Adapter (5V 2A) and an 8GB SD Card with the Raspberry Pi software. Here's the link: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Raspberry-Pi-2-QUAD-Core-BLACK-Case-Complete-8GB-Wifi-Bundle-2015-Model-/171672938217?hash=item27f88126e9:g:iQoAAOSwyQtVi9SJ. The only problem is, the Starter Learning Kit says the components are for the Raspberry Pi 2 B/B+ and I was just wondering if all the components would be compatible with the different model I'm getting. It doesn't state "The components are NOT compatible for the Raspberry Pi 2" but it says this in the title of the product: RFID Starter Learning Kit for Raspberry Pi 2 Model B/B+ Python Servo DC Motor (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/RFID-Starter-Learning-Kit-for-Raspberry-Pi-2-Model-B-B-Python-Servo-DC-Motor-/231698071764?hash=item35f24800d4:g:8OcAAOSwTapV4qSW). If anyone could help me out here and clear up the confusion it would be appreciated, thanks. (I don't really care about the fact the product is from China, if they do give me faulty components I could always get a refund).

Comment: Any good reasons to rollback the edit? Just like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 2 **IS** a Raspberry Pi 2 model B. The components will be compatible.

Comment: Well, in terms of form factor it's more a B+.  I dunno when they started calling it the "2 B"  but I think it was kind of a colloquialism that became official.  Anyway, in relation to that kit the one model specific thing I notice is the 40-pin ribbon cable, which will fit on a + or 2 ("B") model but not a ("1") A or B.   In any case you're right about the components.

Comment: I saw a prototype several months before release and it already said "raspberry pi 2 model B" at that point.